# Can we have a subgroup of order $20$ for a group of order $30$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Here is the problem: we have to show that there does not exist a subgroup of order $20$ when the whole group itself has the order $30$.

Is using Lagrange's theorem sufficient i.e. $|G|/|H|=30/20=3/2$ is not an integer, thus the group of order $30$ cannot have a subgroup of order $20$?

Comment: You  are  right by using Lagrange's theorem

Comment: Yes, Lagrange theory says exactly that.  And that is exactly what Lagrange theorem means. You are done.  Pat yourself on the back, have a nice dinner and go on to the next question.  Good  job.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Because by Lagrange's theorem, the order of any subgroup divides the order of the group.  And $20\nmid 30$.